# Defining the order of the arguments with argparse - Python

Tags: python, command-line, command, argparse, args

I have the following command line tool:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "A cool application.")
parser.add_argument('positional')
parser.add_argument('--optional1')
parser.add_argument('--optional2')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.positionals
```

The output of `python args.py` is:

```
usage: args.py [-h] [--optional1 OPTIONAL1] [--optional2 OPTIONAL2]
               positional
```

however I would like to have:

```
usage: args.py [-h] positional [--optional1 OPTIONAL1] [--optional2 OPTIONAL2]
```

How could I have that reordering?

Comment: Could you still run it with your desired output ? Reading the API it says the order doesn't really matter with optional and positional arguments. 

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#combining-positional-and-optional-arguments

Answer (score 2):

You would either have to provide your own help formatter, or specify an explicit usage string:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="A cool application.",
    usage="args.py [-h] positional [--optional1 OPTIONAL1] [--optional2 OPTIONAL2]")
```

The order in the help message, though, does not affect the order in which you can specify the arguments. `argparse` processes any defined options left-to-right, then assigns any remaining arguments to the positional parameters from left to right. Options and positional arguments can, for the most part, be mixed.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to each other the order of `positionals` is fixed - that's why they are called that.  But `optionals` (the flagged arguments) can occur in any order, and usually can be interspersed with the postionals (there are some practical constrains when allowing variable length `nargs`.)

For the `usage` line, `argparse` moves the `positionals` to the end of the list, but that just a display convention.

There have been SO questions about changing that display order, but I think that is usually not needed.  If you must change the display order, using  a custom `usage` parameter is the simplest option.  The programming way requires subclassing the help formatter and modifying a key method.